# Spring Websockets not working under custom application context path

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I have application which uses Spring 4.3.5 and spring mvc - apache tiles .

I wrote chat according to this article https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Everything is working correctly, if my whole application context path is root so for example : http://example.com/ I recieve following frames in websocket

```
["SUBSCRIBE\nid:sub-0\ndestination:/chat-messages/TST\n\n\u0000"]
["SEND\ndestination:/chat/message/TST\ncontent-length:52\n\n{\"message\":\"\",\"username\":\"USER\",\"event\":\"ONLINE\"}\u0000"]
["MESSAGE\ndestination:/chat-messages/TST\ncontent-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8\nsubscription:sub-0\nmessage-id:x1jpjyes-1\ncontent-length:230\n\n{..SOME JSON CONTENT....}\u0000"]
```

Problem is that it stops working, If I add some app context ( and I need to do so on my server)
for example : http://example.com/my-app
No messages received <strike>, nor sent</strike>

**UPDATE:** No sending was fixed by adding servletContext.getContextPath() to destination prefixes.

With context, I only got this:

```
["SUBSCRIBE\nid:sub-0\ndestination:/my-app/chat-messages/TST\n\n\u0000"]
["SEND\ndestination:/my-app/chat/message/TST\ncontent-length:52\n\n{\"message\":\"\",\"username\":\"USER\",\"event\":\"ONLINE\"}\u0000"]
```

Here is my configurations:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    private static final String TILES = "/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml";
    private static final String VIEWS = "/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml";
    private static final String RESOURCES_HANDLER = "/resources/";
    private static final String RESOURCES_LOCATION = RESOURCES_HANDLER + "**";

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super
            .requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
        }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver configureTilesViewResolver() {
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer configureTilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(TILES, VIEWS);
        return configurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(RESOURCES_HANDLER).addResourceLocations(
                RESOURCES_LOCATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

WebSocketMesssageBroker

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/chat-messages");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(servletContext.getContextPath() + "/chat");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat-websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And I have a controller to process everything

```
@MessageMapping("/message/{projectId}")
@SendTo("/chat-messages/{projectId}")
public ChatResponse sendMessage(@DestinationVariable String projectId, MessageSent message) throw InterruptedException {

//Send reponse back like user online/offline or message posted 
return new ChatResponse(chatMessage);

}
```

In JSP file I have following JS called

```
var socket = new SockJS('<c:url value="/chat-websocket/"/>');

stompClient.subscribe('<c:url value="/chat-messages/${chatProject.projectId}"/>', function (data) { ....SOME RESPONSE PROCESSING... });

stompClient.send("<c:url value="/chat/message/${chatProject.projectId}"/>", {}, JSON.stringify({.....PAYLOAD TO SEND ---}));
```

and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException</exception-type>
        <location>/signin</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <location>/generalError</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

I do suspect that this might be something with configuration of either tiles or whole dispatcher in web.xml or something like this :/

Would be very greatfull for hints

Comment: I was able to resolve that nothing was sent to Controller by adding servletContext.getContextPath() to destination prefixes. But still I'm not able to recieve anything via subscriber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finnaly able to resolve this issue. It turns out whenever I was creating SockJS subscriber I should pass relative path as param, without any context

(I presume the base websocket opened url already have correct url)

So in order to properly receive subscription events all I had to do was change

```
 stompClient.subscribe('<c:url value="/chat-messages/${chatProject.projectId}"/>', function (data) { ....SOME RESPONSE PROCESSING... });
```

to this:

```
 stompClient.subscribe('/chat-messages/${chatProject.projectId}', function (data) { ....SOME RESPONSE PROCESSING... });
```

(without the **<c:url>** which was returning context path all the time)

So whenever I tried to subscribe to chat-messages using

```
<c:url value="chat-messages/ID">
```

in fact I was subscribing to:

```
my-app/chat-messages/ID
```

and my controller and config was expecting plain relative chat-messages

That's why after adding contextPath to WebSocketController setApplicationDestinationPrefixes, app started sending correct messages

Those are couple of hours I'm not getting back :)